# Error "join not supported" when joining 3 tables in SQLite Database

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I have three tables in my SQLite DB:
Sales_Subset: Sales_Order_ID (PK), Product_Code (FK), Customer_ID (FK), QtySold
FGI_Product: Product_Code (PK), Product_Description
Customer: Customer_ID (PK), Name

I want to select all the fields from all three tables and merge them into a single table. I tried the following code, but I get an error "join not supported". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SELECT Customer.*, FGI_Product.*, Sales_Subset.*
FROM Sales_Subset
INNER JOIN FGI_Product ON Sales_Subset.Product_Code = FGI_Product.Product_Code
INNER JOIN Customer ON Sales_Subset.Customer_ID = Customer.Customer_ID;

Comment: I would like to add that I am using DBeaver, and that I have imported the 3 tables from CSV files using the native CSV database connection in DBeaver.

Comment: is there a way to see what, if anything, DBeaver is doing to the query? because your joins look correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the native CSV DB connection in DBeaver doesn't support joins. The problem is not with the query syntax. The syntax is correct.